# The function is always outputting the wrong area

Tags: c++

```
/** Computes the area of this triangle. @return This triangle's area. */
template<class T>
T Triangle<T>::getArea() const {
    double s, area;
    s= (side1+side2+side3)/2;
    area = sqrt(s*(s-side1) * (s-side2)* (s-side3));
    return  area;

}
```

The expected output is 9. I'm using google test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a very simple mistake in your code. When you declared your `double` variable, you also need to declare numbers with floating point. So for your code, you just need to put zero(.0) after 2.

```
s =( side1 +side2+side3)/2.0;
```

Comment: HaHa yeah, how can I make such mistake. Thanks for catching that.